# power shell script need to run on multiple systems but not able to loop through given list of computers

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $compute = Get-Content D:\www\Comp.txt
Get-Content $compute | Foreach-Object {Get-RemoteProgram  -Property Publisher,InstallDate,DisplayVersion,InstallSource,IsMinorUpgrade,ReleaseType,ParentDisplayName,SystemComponent  | Where-Object {[string]$_.SystemComponent -ne 1 -and ![string]$_.IsMinorUpgrade -and ![string]$_.ReleaseType -and ![string]$_.ParentDisplayName} | Format-Table -auto -wrap | Out-File  -FilePath "D:\www\g4.txt"  -Append }
Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At line:2 char:13
+ Get-Content $compute | Foreach-Object {Get-RemoteProgram  -Property Publisher,In ...
+             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Comment: Please check [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently you don't have one, you're using custom cmdlets and it's telling you what the issue is. So it's unclear what you might be stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditto to what Seth says...

That being said, your post gives the impression that you are just coming to grips with PowerShell, which is fine, as we all had to start from somewhere. Yet, there are some really basic PowerShell things wrong in your code.

You are reading in the content of a file using this...

```
$compute = Get-Content D:\www\Comp.txt
```

... which is fine, but you are not showing what is in that file, then, with this ...

```
Get-Content $compute | 
Foreach-Object {
Get-RemoteProgram  -Property Publisher,InstallDate,DisplayVersion,InstallSource,IsMinorUpgrade,ReleaseType,ParentDisplayName,SystemComponent  | 
Wher e-Object {
    [string]$_.SystemComponent -ne 1 -and ![string]$_.IsMinorUpgrade -and ![string]$_.ReleaseType -and ![string]$_.ParentDisplayName} | 
    Format-Table -auto -wrap | 
    Out-File  -FilePath "D:\www\g4.txt"  -Append
}
```

... you are trying to read in variable content, which you have no real need to do, again, since you already have this stored. So, simplify, by doing this...

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\www\Comp.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {}
```

I am also unsure why you feel the need to cast these as strings when you'll get that from the property return value anyway, by default. So, jus this...

```
    $_.SystemComponent -ne 1 -and !$_.IsMinorUpgrade -and !$_.ReleaseType -and !$_.ParentDisplayName
```

Also, try to avoid shorthand in scripts, it makes them a challenge to deal with for those who follow you or whom you may pass this on to. There are several articles that discuss this non-Shorthand thing, so not a personal opinion. They are great for quick interactive stuff though.

[Essential PowerShell: Avoid shorthand in shared PowerShell scripts](https://poshoholic.com/2007/09/06/essential-powershell-avoid-shorthand-in-shared-powershell-scripts)

There is no such cmdlet called Get-RemoteProgram in PowerShell proper, which means either you did this cmdlet / function yourslef or got it from somewhere else. A quick hit on the MS Powershellgallery, shows a similarly named script. So, I am going to assume that is where you got this.

```
Find-Module -Name '*RemoteProgram*' | Ft -a
Find-Command -Name '*RemoteProgram*' | Ft -a
Find-Script -Name '*RemoteProgram*' | Ft -a

Version Name              Repository Description                                                                                                     
------- ----              ---------- -----------                                                                                                     
1.2.1   [Get-RemoteProgram PSGallery][2]  This function generates a list by querying the registry and returning the installed programs of a local or re...


# Load the script
. .\Get-RemoteProgram.ps1

# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-RemoteProgram).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-RemoteProgram -Full
Get-help -Name Get-RemoteProgram -Online
Get-help -Name Get-RemoteProgram -Examples

Get-RemoteProgram
Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName server01,server02
Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName Server01 -Property DisplayVersion,VersionMajor
'server01','server02' | Get-RemoteProgram -Property Uninstallstring
'server01','server02' | Get-RemoteProgram -Property Uninstallstring -ExcludeSimilar -SimilarWord 4
Get-RemoteProgram -Property installdate,uninstallstring,installlocation -LastAccessTime | Where-Object {$_.installlocation}
Get-RemoteProgram -Property installdate -IncludeProgram *office*
Get-RemoteProgram -Property installdate -IncludeProgram 'Microsoft Office Access','Microsoft SQL Server 2014'
Get-RemoteProgram -IncludeProgram ^Office -ProgramRegExMatch
```

So, looking at what the author states are its goals and your use of it. You should really just need something link the below. Taking advantage of PowerShell natural line break to make this more readiable, well, some would say so. It's a choice. Don't use Format if you are sending output to a file as that Format is for the screen and it will get truncated when you do that in a file, unless you code for it.

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\www\Comp.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName $PSItem -Property Publisher, InstallDate, DisplayVersion,
    InstallSource, IsMinorUpgrade, ReleaseType, ParentDisplayName, SystemComponent  | 
    Where-Object {
        $PSItem.SystemComponent -ne 1 -and 
        -Not $PSItem.IsMinorUpgrade -and 
        -Not $PSItem.ReleaseType -and 
        -Not $PSItem.ParentDisplayName} | 
        Out-File -FilePath 'D:\www\g4.txt' -Append
}

notepad 'D:\www\g4.txt'

# Results


ComputerName      : WS01
ProgramName       : 7-Zip 18.01 (x64)
Publisher         : Igor Pavlov
InstallDate       : 
DisplayVersion    : 18.01
InstallSource     : 
IsMinorUpgrade    : 
ReleaseType       : 
ParentDisplayName : 
SystemComponent   : 

ComputerName      : WS01
ProgramName       : SAPIEN Document Explorer 2019
Publisher         : SAPIEN Technologies, Inc.
InstallDate       : 
DisplayVersion    : 3.1.88.0
InstallSource     : 
IsMinorUpgrade    : 
ReleaseType       : 
ParentDisplayName : 
SystemComponent   : 

ComputerName      : WS01
ProgramName       : Git version 2.21.0
Publisher         : The Git Development Community
InstallDate       : 20190227
DisplayVersion    : 2.21.0
InstallSource     : 
IsMinorUpgrade    : 
ReleaseType       : 
ParentDisplayName : 
SystemComponent   : 

...
```

So, spend some time on YouTube and MSDN Channel9 reviewing and learning from the beginner, intermediate, advanced, etc., videos there. So, this will aid you in limiting mistakes, confusions, bad habits, etc., as you go forward.

***Update for the OP***

As for :

> how do i export this in csv

Just change this...

```
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\www\g4.txt' -Append
```

... to this...

```
Export-Csv -Path 'D:\www\g4.txt-Append -NoTypeInformation
```

***Update for OP***

You should be getting the below, not lengths.

```
. .\Get-RemoteProgram.ps1
$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName $PSItem -Property Publisher, InstallDate, DisplayVersion,
    InstallSource, IsMinorUpgrade, ReleaseType, ParentDisplayName, SystemComponent  | 
    Where-Object {
        $PSItem.SystemComponent -ne 1 -and 
        -Not $PSItem.IsMinorUpgrade -and 
        -Not $PSItem.ReleaseType -and 
        -Not $PSItem.ParentDisplayName} | 
        Export-Csv -Path 'F:\temp\g4.txt' -Append -NoTypeInformation
}



Get-Content -Path 'F:\temp\g4.txt'

# Results


"ComputerName","ProgramName","Publisher","InstallDate","DisplayVersion","InstallSource","IsMinorUpgrade","ReleaseType","ParentDisplayName","SystemComponent"
"WS01","7-Zip 18.01 (x64)","Igor Pavlov",,"18.01",,,,,
"WS01","SAPIEN Document Explorer 2019","SAPIEN Technologies, Inc.",,"3.1.88.0",,,,,
...




Import-Csv -Path 'F:\temp\g4.txt' | 
Format-Table


# Results

ComputerName ProgramName                                                          Publisher                                                    InstallDate Disp
                                                                                                                                                           layV
                                                                                                                                                           ersi
                                                                                                                                                           on  
------------ -----------                                                          ---------                                                    ----------- ----
WS01         7-Zip 18.01 (x64)                                                    Igor Pavlov                                                              1...
WS01         SAPIEN Document Explorer 2019                                        SAPIEN Technologies, Inc.                                                3...
WS01         Git version 2.21.0                                                   The Git Development Community                                20190227    2...
```

Comment: thank you very much for ur kind explanation

Comment: No worries. Jus remember, if this solved you use case, make it as you accepted answer for the benefit of us all.

Comment: how do i export  this in csv

Comment: See my update for you.

Comment: i did try ,but its gave only length

Comment: What did you change on your side. I tested this before posting, So, I do know it works. Se the sample room one of my machines, in the update.

Comment: its working fine but i am trying to add line before every loop like, write-output "$PSItem  processing" to make output more identical

Comment: Do that as the first line after the brace of the ForEach, if you mean you wan this as a screen display only. If you mean you want this do display in the file, then that is a problem for a csv proper. As csv are rows and columns only - table, no separate title / message stuff. In the csv file, nothing should be above the header row. On the screen, you can do what you wish.

Comment: thats mess then because some times server are reachable but still issue in fetching the data,how would get to know if dont get data for particular server

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
$compute = Get-Content D:\www\Comp.txt
Get-Content $compute
```

You're reading in a file from D:\ww\Comp.txt.  You're then trying to read in whatever is in that file as another path..  if D:\ww\Comp.txt contained "MyPC" - you're then trying to Get-Content on "MyPC"

Try something like this instead:

```
$computers = Get-Content D:\Computers.txt
$Computers | ForEach {
    #DO STUFF
}
```

You're also not telling the PowerShell script to use the remote computer in your script:

```
Get-RemoteProgram  -Property Publisher,InstallDate,DisplayVersion,InstallSource,IsMinorUpgrade,ReleaseType,ParentDisplayName,SystemComponent
```

(in this case - you may be inside a loop, but this command isnt being told to execute against a remote computer)

Because your PowerShell script isnt a standard cmdlet - I am assuming, you are using this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4

This script takes a `-ComputerName` switch - so you should be trying something like:

```
Get-RemoteProgram  -ComputerName $_ -Property Publisher,InstallDate,DisplayVersion,InstallSource,IsMinorUpgrade,ReleaseType,ParentDisplayName,SystemComponent
```

There are a couple of other bits in the script which could use attention such as `FT` being piped to `Out-File`.  If you want a grid in a file - try `Export-csv` instead.

Putting it all together - I think you are looking for something like this (Edit, this script has been updated to reflect the additional help requested in comments):

```
$ComputerList = Get-Content D:\Computers.txt

$ComputerList | ForEach {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1) {
        Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName $_ -Property Publisher,InstallDate,DisplayVersion,InstallSource,IsMinorUpgrade,ReleaseType,ParentDisplayName,SystemComponent | Where {
            [string]$_.SystemComponent -ne 1 -and ![string]$_.IsMinorUpgrade -and ![string]$_.ReleaseType -and ![string]$_.ParentDisplayName
        } | Export-Csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Results.csv
    } else {
        $_ | Out-File D:\UncontactableMachines.txt -Append
    }
}
```

As a side note - most (if not all of this) can be done through `Get-WMIObject` or `Get-CIMInstance` without the need for bringing in the external `Get-RemoteProgram` cmdlet/function

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for ur kind explanation

Comment: dear friend ,could you help me with this,i am not able to export it in CSV

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: actuall i am trying to add test-connection to see first if the system is reachable or not ,but after adding if else ,the script not working

Comment: I've updated the bottom part of my answer to show you how you can work with a test-connection before invoking.

Comment: Write-Output "$_ processing.."  how do i add this in this code,

Comment: Hi,  Unfortuinately, I do not have time to keep editing my answer as you expand on further problems.  Please post a new question with your code as an example and someone (possibly even myself) will be able to help further.